# why is this expression returning true

Tags: java, string, expression

`(pass[i]!= null) && (pass[i].getName()!= "nullnull")` <--returning true when I debug it even though the value of `pass[i].getName() == "nullnull"` when I check it using the Expressions window in eclipse while debugging

im using the input dialog box to input two names

```
String firstName = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter First Name");
String lastName = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Last Name");
```

and returning

```
public String getName()
    {
        return FirstName + LastName;
    }
```

Comment: Without context, your question is meaningless

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two different strings with the same value, but you're comparing them by reference.

You need to compare them by value by writing `"nullnull".equals(pass[i].getName())`.
The reversed order will work even if `getName()` returns `null`.

Answer (score 4):

Try using ".equals"

```
(pass[i]!= null) && !(pass[i].getName().equals("nullnull"))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need

```
    (pass[i]!= null) && (!pass[i].getName().equals("nullnull"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings should not be compared with `==` or `!=`.
Use `String.equals()`.

`==` will return true and `!=` will return false only when both Strings are the same string object (which is different from comparing the text they represent).

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, it's almost always going to be true:

In java the `==` operator comparer object references. you want the `.equals()` method.

There's a gap in your code - it will explode if `getName()` returns `null`.

Comment: Not necessarily a gap at all. If you document that a certain property can't be null (and protect that invariant) then there is no problem. It's actually better design and leads to much cleaner code.  In this case it certainly won't be null because `Firstname + Lastname` is null safe and will never return null.